# call jar file from ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jar

How to call `jar` file (a java archive file) from `ruby` class. And access the functions/methods from it.

I am refering the following [link](http://kgilmersden.wordpress.com/2010/09/30/call-your-java-method-from-your-ruby-class/)

But I am getting the following error:

`'require': cannot load such file -- /tmp/Test.jar (LoadError)`

How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a system call. You may have performance issues if you have lots of users, but for most this should work:

```
# Create a directory (in this sample called "jars") inside public directory and move your jar file inside the newly created directory.

def externaljar

 argsA = ""
 argsB = ""

    Dir.chdir("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/jars/") do

        # Use your path to the java according to the java directory installed in your machine.

        retResult  = system("/home/user/java/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -jar JSpell.jar #{argsA} #{argsB}")

    end #chdir
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call Java code from Ruby. You might want to have a look at [JRuby](http://jruby.org). JRuby is what the guy from your link uses, you can see it when he types `jruby Main.rb` in the console.

Comment: Can i call a function from jar file ?

Comment: @user1881251 Not from MRI (standard Ruby). Get JRuby. Or mess with bindings from C to Java. You might want to go with JRuby at this point

Comment: This is not correct. You can make system calls within MRI to call a jar. See Open3 in the MRI std-lib.