# How to pass parameters to a jar file and read the console output in ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, jar

I'm trying to execute a .jar file from ruby and read the output. The following solution works when my .jar file does not expect any parameters to be passed. But when I try to do this, I get an error -

```
pipe = IO.popen( [ '/path/to/java', '-jar', "/path/to/jarfile.jar #{argsA} #{argsB}", {SDTERR=>STDOUT} ] 
pipe.close_write 
puts pipe.readlines
```

I need to pass a couple of parameters to the .jar file. How can I acheive this? I've tried several ways to do this but wasn't successful. This is the error I get, where 'Hello' and 'World' are the arguments I'm passing -

> Error: Unable to access jarfile jarfile.jar Hello World

Useful links:
[How to get java output with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354602/how-to-get-java-output-with-ruby?nah=29826744#29826744)

[call jar file from ruby class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174068/call-jar-file-from-ruby-class)

Comment: Have you tried passing the .jar filename and the arguments as separate elements in the array passed to `IO.popen`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that out yesterday and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put argsA and argsB in their own parameter, otherwise when seeing spaces in the parameters, ruby will surround them with quotes, so they're considered like one.

```
pipe = IO.popen( [ '/path/to/java', '-jar', '/path/to/jarfile.jar',"#{argsA}", "#{argsB}", {SDTERR=>STDOUT} ]
```